# How can I take an input for the installation location in my MSI using Wix Toolset?

Tags: input, wix, windows-installer

You know how when installing an application using an MSI, the installation location can be manually changed from the default? Is there a way to replicate this using Wix? I'm not familiar with UI creation, so if there is a way to take input from command line to set the destination folder, that would be great.

Comment: Not sure if that's two questions but [Using Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) and [`msiexec /?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841965/2226988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install msi with msiexec in a Specific Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839978/install-msi-with-msiexec-in-a-specific-directory)