# How to install 7z from powershell to a specified directory

Tags: powershell, 7zip, windows-installer

How to install 7z from powershell to a specified directory? I am trying to do so using the msi/exe available here: https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

The installtion always gets happends to "C:/Program Files/7-zip" even with below command:

```
  msiexec /i "7z1604-x64.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Downloads" /q
```

How can I choose the installation path?

Comment: Are you sure about the msi property? If I'm not wrong it should be `INSTALLDIR` instead of `TARGETDIR`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that msiexec /i doesn't respect TARGET parameret but try Administrative Installation:

`msiexec /a "7z1604-x64.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Downloads" /q`

[Install msi with msiexec in a Specific Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839978/install-msi-with-msiexec-in-a-specific-directory)

But why somebody still needs 2016 version 7z in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

The easy to do this :

```
msiexec.exe /i https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.msi
```